# Font for the normal sheaf N_D of a divisor D

Tags: fonts, math-mode

What kind of package / font should I use to get the following version of the capital N in math mode?

[image]

This is the standard notation for the normal sheaf associated to the divisor D.

Comment: `$\mathcal{N}_{D}$`. See [How to look up a symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Answer (score 1):

`$\mathcal{N}_D$` should give you what you're looking for.  You don't need to load any special packages.